# How do I make CSS find my static images whilst using Flask?

Tags: html, css, flask

I have a problem I'm trying to solve using flask and css. Currently I have an index.html file that I want to use a banner on. So in my main.css:

```css
#banner {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  padding: 8em 0 6em 0;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-image: url("{{ url_for('/static', filename='images/frambay_Banner.jpg') }}");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh !important;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

As you can see, I'm already trying out the jinja2-approach to have my file be found, which is under

/static/images/frambay_Banner.jpg
while my css file is found under
/static/css/main.css.

I have also tried to use the usual url(...) instead of url_for. When using the form I posted in my index.html directly, the background image is displayed correctly. This is the content of my main.py:
`

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template  

app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route("/")  
def home():  
    return render_template("index.html")  

@app.route("/wipe")  
def wipe():  
    return render_template("generic.html")   

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app.run()
```

`

Comment: There is no need to use jinja2 related syntax like url_for, a simple url("path/to/banner.png") should be enough.

Comment: I've tried that, by using background-image: url("../images/frambay_Banner.jpg"), but flask still prints out a 404 Error

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image: url("/static/images/frambay_Banner.jpg")
```